# Using an exponential cipher system, encipher the word HALT. where $p = 29, k = 11$, and $m = 1$.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Using an exponential cipher system, encipher the word HALT. where $p = 29, k = 11$, and $m = 1$.

The progress I have made so far:

H A L T

$07, 00,11,19$

Since, $m =1$, we break this up into $2*m$ pieces, giving us $2$.

$0700$ and $1119$

From here we have to calculate the C value for each which is congruent to $p^k \pmod p$

The two congruences I get are:

a.) $0700^{11} \pmod 29$

b.) $1119^{11} \pmod 29$

- After this I began to get a bit lost, my professor used repeated squares but I can't quite get it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe the exponential cipher system or at least define it in the problem as this question is is hard to follow? Also, did you mean $\pmod {29}$?

Answer (score 1):

From what I make of the question, this might be helpful for you...

Note that $11 = 2^3 + 2^1 + 2^0$ re-writing the exponent as the sum of powers of $2$.

Then the modular equation becomes:

$700^{11} \equiv 700^{2^3 + 2^1 + 2^0} \equiv 700^{2^{3}} \cdot 700^{2^1} \cdot 700^{2^0} $mod $29$

Now proceed with Square and Reduce method (I'll show you the first couple of steps):

$700^{2^0} \equiv 700 \equiv 4$ mod $29$

$700^{2^1} \equiv 4^{2} \equiv 16$ mod $29$

$700^{2^2} \equiv 16^{2} \equiv 24$ mod $29$

Say $700^{2^3} \equiv x$ mod $29$

Then $700^{13} \equiv x \cdot 16 \cdot 700$ mod $29$

Hope this helps